# how to extract subtitle stream from a video with javascript

Tags: javascript, web, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm trying to display subtitles of a video, I have a video with an embedded subtitle stream in it,

[image]

it showing subtitle stream on `ffprobe` but not on javascript, tried with captureStream API which will return MediaStream object to see the available tracks but it's only returning audio/video tracks not subtitle tracks

[image]

guessing web standard doesn't have a spec to return all the tracks other than audio/video
it will be helpful if you have a solution for this.
but I appreciate your help. thanks.

Comment: Does captureStream API support "mov_text" streaming text subtitle format (14496-17)? For next time please copy and paste text instead of making images of text. [See reasons why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).